# detour hooking usermode functions from the kernel

Tags: c++, c, winapi, kernel, driver

I have a kernel mode driver and I'm trying to implement a way so that I can make usermode hooks from it. I need to hook usermode functions via detour/jmp from the kernel.

Comment: inject dll from driver to user mode process

Comment: My intention is to create the hooks from kernel, i can't go usermode.

Comment: but how this related to my comment ? inject dll from driver to process.

Comment: No i want to make a detour from kernel mode. Injecting a dll into the target process ruins the whole point of having the driver and is not a valid option for my case.

Comment: where will be placed hook function ? in your driver in this case. the page protection - not let execute it in user mode code. and no support for this from system. you need found *PTE* for your pages in driver and set Owner bit. only this is enough for not do this. *Injecting a dll into the target process ruins the whole point of having the driver* - no, driver and will be do inject

Answer (score 0):

To perform an external detour from kernel you do the same thing you do in usermode except instead of WriteProcessMemory you would use NtWriteVirtualMemory.

The problem this idea presents is: where are you jumping to?  You can't jump into the kernel, so you are still left with the problem of getting your code into the target process.  You can write shellcode, inject a DLL etc...

But the whole purpose of using the driver is to bypass protection and detection mechanisms.  A mature anti-debug detection solution will detect you writing your jump and writing your shellcode via memory integrity checks.

The solution isn't as simple as "go kernel", you need to nullify the protection and detection mechanism from kernel first.

If you've nullified the detection/protection mechanism then you might as well inject a DLL and just perform a normal usermode detour at that point.